# Execute script in new gnome-terminal loading bashrc

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I have a script in a gnome-terminal shell and I would like to open a new terminal, load the bashrc configuration, execute a new script and avoid the closure of the new terminal window.

I have tried to execute this commands:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash
```

the script above open a new shell and loads bashrc, but I don't know how to execute a script automatically.

```
gnome-terminal -x ./new_script.sh
```

the script above open a new shell and execute the script but doesn't load bashrc and close the window.

---

The result that I would like to obtain is to feel like opening a new terminal as clicking the term icon but execute a script after the bashrc setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
gnome-terminal -e command
```

or

```
xterm -e command
```

or

```
konsole -e command
```

Pretty much

```
terminal -e command
```

To make the terminal stay when the command exits:

In `konsole` there is a `--noclose` flag.

In `xterm`, there is a `-hold` flag.

In gnome-terminal, go to `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title`. Click the Command tab. Select Hold the terminal from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits. You should create a new profile for that and execute with

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't see the bashrc output when I run `gnome-terminal -e ./new_script.sh  --window-with-profile=my_profile`. Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper script that basically looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
./new-script.sh
bash
```

And then run `[terminal] -e wrapper-script.sh`.

The `-i` flag in the shebang will make the wrapper script run in interactive mode, so it will load `.bashrc`; then it will run `new-script.sh`, and then it'll start a new bash instance so you can run whatever commands you want afterwards in that instance.

(Or you can put the -i flag on the shebang of the `./new-script.sh` if wanted it always to do that.)

If you don't want to be able to run commands afterwards, but just want the terminal to hold open, then you can leave out the second `bash` and use whatever flag or setting or profile is appropriate for doing that depending on the terminal.